# The probability of choosing two diamond cards and three spade cards

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you are playing regular cards. You can be announced a winner if in your hand of five cards
you happen to have two diamond cards and three spade cards. What is the probability of winning the
game? Please write through combination numbers and then calculate the whole fraction.

My solution: $\frac{\left(\begin{matrix}{13 \\ 2}\end{matrix} \right)\left(\begin{matrix} 13 \\ 3 \end{matrix}\right)}{\left(\begin{matrix}52 \\ 5\end{matrix}\right)} = \frac{13 \cdot 6 \cdot 13 \cdot 2 \cdot 11}{52 \cdot 17 \cdot 10 \cdot 6 \cdot 49} = \frac{169 \cdot 11}{52 \cdot 17 \cdot 5 \cdot 49} \approx 0.0086$.

Is this correct, if not, where is the mistake?

Comment: Seems OK. But be careful about generalizing. That's also the probability of getting two diamonds and three clubs, etc. So the probability of two cards of any one suite and three of any other is larger.

Comment: @BruceET Ok, and if the problem states that the winner is only the one who has specifically spade and diamond cards, then how could I specify the computation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer looks correct.

Probabilities can sometimes be counter-intuitive, so sometimes is it a good idea to approach them a few different ways to see if they match (and if they don't then look for why not).

So I wrote a quick R script to simulate this and see if I get similar results to you:

```
simfun <- function() {
  tmp <- sample(rep(c('S','H','C','D'), each=13), 5)
  all(sort(tmp) == c('D','D','S','S','S'))
}

out <- replicate(1000000, simfun())
mean(out)

prop.test(sum(out), length(out))
```

This took only about a minute to run (could run for more iterations and fairly quick if I parallelized).  Your answer of 0.0086 was in the 95% confidence interval which gives weight to your answer being correct.

Comment: Your simulation is four times longer than the total number of five-card hands, so you would be better off doing a brute force enumeration!  For instance, `mean(colSums(combn(c(rep(0,13), rep(1,13), rep(5,26)), 5))==3)` takes about one second, returning $0.00858343337334932 = 143 / 16660 = (11)(13)/((2^2)(5)(7^2)(17)).$

Comment: @whuber, good point, for this case we can look at all possibilities in a reasonable time (actually better than my simulation as you point out).  But the idea of simulation is still good to think about for more complicated cases where the number of possibilities is much larger.